# Why is my Android UI acting wonky whenever I try to select text?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am working on an Android app (API 15 and below). In my UI I have a TextView element that I would like people to be able to select and copy from. Here is what my element looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This TextView sits within a ListView that is populated with a SimpleCursorAdapter. This ListView looks like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_text_display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/WHITE"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:divider_height="0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
```

The ListView is within a LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat_text_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/WHITE"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/text_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/chat_button"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_text_compose"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@color/WHITE"
            android:hint="@string/chat_hint"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever I try to single-click the text in chat_info or chat_message, nothing happens. However, whenever I try to double-click the text:

1. my entire UI shifts down
2. a "toolbar" shows up at the top of the screen
3. the "toolbar" immediately goes away and my display shifts back up

In the "toolbar" this is what I see:

[image]

It looks like it is the copy dialog, but it goes away immediately.

I can insert a "stand alone" TextView within the LinearLayout with a `android:textIsSelectable="true"` and the copy dialog works as it should; meaning that it will stay visible until I have selected "copy".

The last piece of information I can offer is that my LinearLayout is within a tabbed activity using fragments with a ViewPager. I just don't see how this can be the issue because, like I said, I can add another element (e.g., TextView) within the LinearLayout and the Copy dialog acts perfectly. I thought I would add this piece for full clarity.

All I am wanting to do is select the text in chat_info or chat_message so I can copy and paste the text elsewhere.

Any ideas?

**NEW INFORMATION!!!**

When I select the text in the "chat_text_compose" EditText, the Copy toolbar appears normally. At this point, I **can** successfully select the text in my TextView areas. Weird.

**UPDATE: The code that controls this layout**

```
public class Chat extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        displayChats();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        displayChats();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        final Button sendChatButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_send);
        final EditText chatEntryWindow = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_compose);

        // Check to see if the text entry field is empty. If it is empty, disable the "Send" button.
        chatEntryWindow.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() != 0){
                    sendChatButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    sendChatButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });

        // Send the chat
        if(sendChatButton != null) {
            sendChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Date rightNow = new Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat timeSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SIMPLE_TIME, Locale.US);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SIMPLE_DATE, Locale.US);
                    SharedPreferences myAppPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String message = chatEntryWindow.getText().toString();
                    String username = myAppPreferences.getString("username", Constants.TABLET_ID);
                    Message myMessage = new Message(true, username, message, 0, dateSDF.format(rightNow), timeSDF.format(rightNow));
                    if(!message.equals("")){
                        LogChat logChat = new LogChat(getActivity());
                        logChat.addNewMessage(myMessage);
                        new SendChat(getActivity(), message, username).execute();
                        chatEntryWindow.setText("");
                        sendChatButton.setEnabled(false);
                        if(v != null){
                            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                        displayChats();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return super.getView();
    }

    public void displayChats(){
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        final Cursor chatsCursor = myDBHelper.getChatsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"messageInfo","messageText"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.chat_information, R.id.chat_message};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.line_of_chat, chatsCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_display);

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would just like to select the text in chat_info or chat_message so that I can copy and paste it elsewhere.

Comment: If toolbar with edit options would stay and hasn't gone it would bo all right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I can copy from other TextView elements in my UI, just not from this particular TextView setup.

Comment: Ok, let me ask again: when exactly it happened? > the "toolbar" immediately goes away and my display shifts back up

Comment: I double-click or long click on the text I want to select. The Copy toolbar appears for half a second or so, then immediately goes away; without me selecting or copying any text. When the Copy toolbar appears, it shifts my UI down to accommodate its appearance, then my UI shifts back up when the Copy toolbar goes away.

Comment: Try don't use `android:layout_weight` for a moment and try again. Also add `android:focusable="true"`
    `android:longClickable="true"` to parent `LinearLayout`

Comment: That did not work. I took it off the TextViews and I took it off the ListView (first TextView, then TextView and ListView, then just ListView).

Comment: Is it possible that your double click is highlighting the text you desire, bringing up a toolbar, which shifts your ListView and gains focus, causing your TextView to lose focus which would remove the option to "copy" it, closing the toolbar and shifting things back?

Comment: @zgc7009 Maybe ... but I have no idea how to determine if this is what is happening, or how to fix it if it is.

Comment: Try throwing a focus change listener on a text view and throwing some logs out to see if/when focus is shifting

Comment: Why are you using TextView, when you want EditText ?

Comment: @JonGoodwin I don't want EditText. I want to be able to copy out of the TextView and paste it into an EditText.

Comment: @zgc7009 Like I said, I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter and I'm not sure where to "grab" the TextView as it's populating the list so I can set the onFocusChangeListener.

Comment: Adding `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` to your theme will prevent shifting.

Comment: What, if any, listeners do you have attached to your TextView?

Without seeing any code beyond the XML, it sounds like you have a listener that's attempting to modify the ListView when text is selected. That action then causes the ListView to repopulate of your listview, which removes all the sub-views (causing you to lose focus), and then adds them back.

Comment: @Eric I have no listeners attached to the TextView. I can post the chat fragment if you would like to see it.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, go ahead and post it. I'm curious about how/when you are refreshing the ListView.

Comment: @Eric Ok ... the code is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an FYI, just in case anybody else comes around looking for an answer.

I gave up on trying it this way, using "android:textIsSelectable='true'", and went another route. Instead, I set an "onItemLongClickListener()" and used the ClipboardManager to grab the text within the chat:

```
public void displayChats(){
        final Context context = getContext();
        final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        final Cursor chatsCursor = myDBHelper.getChatsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"messageInfo","messageText"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.chat_information, R.id.chat_message};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.line_of_chat, chatsCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_display);

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        myListView.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                TextView chatText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
                ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("copied chat", chatText.getText.toString());
                if(clipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "copied text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        myDBHelper.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CustomAdapter` as you need to set `registerForContextMenu()` to your both of `TextViews` as follows.

```
registerForContextMenu(holder.chatMessage);
registerForContextMenu(holder.chatInfo);
```

Use `onCreateContextMenu` to create `context menu` and to show the selected text

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    menu.setHeaderTitle(textView.getText()).add(0, 0, 0, R.string.menu_copy_to_clipboard);
    clipBoardText = textView.getText().toString();
}
```

And use `onContextItemSelected` for copying the text to `clip board`

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        final android.content.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.content.ClipboardManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        final android.content.ClipData clipData = android.content.ClipData
                .newPlainText("label", clipBoardText);
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
    } else {
        ((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(clipBoardText);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried with this. You have to long click on the `textView` from which you want the text to be copied. It shows a `dialog` and after you click copy text, the text will be copied to `clipboard`. You can paste it anywhere you want. The example I have tried is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86ba95da90dfa4d2e9bf97141f61aac3).

Comment: @Brian is my answer helpful? If not please clarify I will try my level best to solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Single click is expected.  Android doesn't hilight on single click.

You're entering the action mode for copy paste.  An action mode is a state of an activity where the toolbar switches out for a context aware set of commands (in this case copy/paste commands).  It seems like you're entering it and then immediately exiting it, possibly because you're losing focus to another element.

Comment: _where the toolbar switches out for a context aware set of commands_ I am not using the toolbar; my UI is full screen. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hmm.  Never tried to see.  That could be it, it does explain why the screen moved down-  the toolbar is being moved in.  It may explain why its going away too, the relayout may take away focus.  I can't say so for sure though.  An easy check would be to turn off fullscreen as a test and see if it still has an issue.

Comment: How do I go about turning off fullscreen? Thanks.

Comment: FYI ... I just discovered that it is not a toolbar issue. I put the toolbar back and my problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `registerForContextMenu(yourTextView);`,your `TextView` will be registered for receiving context menu events. And you will be able to get text from your textview into clipboard using `OnCreateContextMenu`.

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    //user has long pressed your TextView
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "your text...copy blbblaba");

    //cast the received View to TextView so that you can get its text
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) v;

    //place your TextView's text in clipboard
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    clipboard.setText(yourTextView.getText());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `registerForContextMenu(yourTextView);` Like I said, I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter and I'm not sure where to "grab" the TextView as it's populating the list.